# Why my gnome-terminal cant set colorscheme

Tags: vim, gnome, color-scheme, gnome-terminal

I can't set up vim colorschemes([sexy-railscast](https://github.com/oguzbilgic/sexy-railscasts-theme) and others) with 256 colors. How to check where the problem is?

In [my vimrc](https://gist.github.com/1968754) I have `:echo has("gui") => 1` but when I added `set t_Co=256` nothing happens.

Also in `.~/.profile` I added: `export TERM="gnome-256color"`

[image]

Comment: What produces that nice footer?

Comment: plugin ``vim-powerline``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sexy-railscasts-theme](https://github.com/oguzbilgic/sexy-railscasts-theme) seams to be a *a GUI only port* and gnome-terminal isn't a GUI for Vim.

So, maybe trying gVim instead will fix your problem.

Comment: I used this gem to use gui only colorscheme.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390

Comment: yeah but i advise u to go for gvim. After spending a lot under gnome-term and vim.. i found that gvim is better for 2 reasons: 1. gvim has alt key support :P  2. gvim's color scheme is indep and unaffacted by gnome-term :)

Comment: gnome-terinal also have ALT key support. You can just ```map <Esc>j``` and now you have ```<Alt> + j``` shourcut

Comment: oww i tried various stuf to make it work.. didnt get anywhere. I'll try this. Thx :D